# Suppose $X_n$ are iid with a symmetric distribution. Then $\Sigma_n \frac{X_n}{n}<\infty ~\mathrm{a.s. iff }~\mathbb{E}|X_1|<\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

It seems to be solved by using Kolmogorov strong law of large numbers. Why $X_n$ have symmetric distribution?

Comment: Do you really mean $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{X_n}{n}$? If so, you are dealing with triangular arrays and I am not sure how to apply the SLLN then.

Comment: This might be killing a fly with a nuke, but Kolmogorov's three-series theorem would be helpful here.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I think that OP is confused, I also thought of K3ST but that is for random series in general. Anyway, the exercise, as OP wrote it, is immediate from K3ST.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike's comment pointed out, by Kolmogorov's three-series theorem, the following three facts implies $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{X_j}{j} <\infty $ almost surely:$$
E|X_1|<\infty \Rightarrow \sum_{j\geq 1} P\left(|\frac{X_j}{j}|\geq 1\right) <\infty , 
$$ 
$$\sum_j E\left[\frac{X_j}{j}1_{|X_j| \leq j}\right]=0,
$$ which follows from symmetry of the distribution of $X_j$, and $$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_j E\left[\left(\frac{X_j}{j}\right)^21_{|X_j| \leq j}\right] &=& \sum_j \frac{1}{j^2}\int_{-j}^j x^2 dF(x) \\&=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \left(\sum_{j\geq 1, j\geq |x|} \frac{1}{j^2}\right)dF(x)\\&\leq&  C\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|dF(x) <\infty,
\end{eqnarray}$$ where $F$ is the distribution function of $X_1$.

Conversely, if $E|X_1|=\infty$, then we should have 
$$
\sum_j P(|X_j|\geq j) = \infty.
$$By Borel-Cantelli lemma, this implies that
$$
|\frac{X_j}{j}|\geq 1, \text{ i.o.}
$$ almost surely. This makes the series $\sum_j \frac{X_j}{j}$ divergent almost surely. We can see this in another way: if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{X_j}{j} <\infty$ with positive probability $p$, then by Kronecker's lemma, we get
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j  \to 0,
$$ with probability $p$. However, if $E|X_1|=\infty$, by the converse of SLLN, we have that
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}|\sum_{j=1}^n X_j| = \infty,
$$ with probability $1$. This contradicts $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{X_j}{j} <\infty$, with positive probability, thus the sum diverges almost surely.